# You do not have permission to access this document Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script

Why i have an error: You do not have permission to access this document. When i'm using "try{}catch(error){}" ? The part with exceptions is done correctly

```
const ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Premia')
  .addItem('Send information', 'sendInfo')
  .addToUi();
   
}
   
function sendInfo() {
try {
PREMIA.importDane(ssID);
}
catch (error) {
  var ui =SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  ui.alert("Error");
}
  
}
```

HERE IS MY LIBRARY CODE PREMIA, HERE IS MY LIBRARY CODE PREMIA, HERE IS MY LIBRARY CODE PREMIA, HERE IS MY LIBRARY CODE PREMIA,HERE IS MY LIBRARY CODE PREMIA, HERE IS MY LIBRARY CODE PREMIA, HERE IS MY LIBRARY CODE PREMIA, HERE IS MY LIBRARY CODE PREMIA,HERE IS MY LIBRARY CODE PREMIA, HERE IS MY LIBRARY CODE PREMIA, HERE IS MY LIBRARY CODE PREMIA, HERE IS MY LIBRARY CODE PREMIA,

```
function importDane(ssID) {

  
   const baza = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID OF MY DATABASE SPREADSHEET');
   const bazaBaza = baza.getSheetByName('Baza');
   const bazaSlownik = baza.getSheetByName('Słownik');
   const bazaSlownikDane = bazaSlownik.getDataRange().getValues();
   //const bazaDostep = baza.getSheetByName("Dostęp").getDataRange().getValues();

  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Premie");
  var dane = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    


  var licznik =0;

  for (var i=2; i<dane.length;i++) {
    if (dane [i][6]=="Wyślij") {

      licznik++;
      var przelozony = dane[0][1];
      var miesiac = dane[i][0];
      var nazwisko = dane[i][1];
      var imie = dane[i][2];
      var pesel = dane[i][3];
      var biuro = dane[i][4];
      var premia = dane[i][5];


      if (miesiac=="Styczeń") {
        for (let a =0;a<bazaSlownikDane.length;a++) {
          if (bazaSlownikDane[a][1]==pesel){
            var wyplata=bazaSlownikDane[a][2];
            var odroczono=(wyplata*0.06);
            var dowyplaty = (premia-odroczono);
            if(dowyplaty<0) {
              dowyplaty=0;
              odroczono=premia;
          }
        }
      }
     } else if (miesiac=="Luty") {
        for (let a =0;a<bazaSlownikDane.length;a++) {
          if (bazaSlownikDane[a][1]==pesel){
            var wyplata=bazaSlownikDane[a][3];
            var odroczono=(wyplata*0.06);
            var dowyplaty = (premia-odroczono);
            if(dowyplaty<0) {
              dowyplaty=0;
              odroczono=premia;
          }
          
        }
      }

     } else if (miesiac=="Marzec") {
        for (let a =0;a<bazaSlownikDane.length;a++) {
          if (bazaSlownikDane[a][1]==pesel){
           var wyplata=bazaSlownikDane[a][4];
            var odroczono=(wyplata*0.06);
            var dowyplaty = (premia-odroczono);
            if(dowyplaty<0) {
              dowyplaty=0;
              odroczono=premia;
          }
          
        }
      }

      } else if (miesiac=="Kwiecień") {
          for (let a =0;a<bazaSlownikDane.length;a++) {
            if (bazaSlownikDane[a][1]==pesel){
              var wyplata=bazaSlownikDane[a][5];
              var odroczono=(wyplata*0.06);
              var dowyplaty = (premia-odroczono);
              if(dowyplaty<0) {
                dowyplaty=0;
                odroczono=premia;
          }
          
        }
      }

      } else if (miesiac=="Maj") {
          for (let a =0;a<bazaSlownikDane.length;a++) {
            if (bazaSlownikDane[a][1]==pesel){
              var wyplata=bazaSlownikDane[a][6];
              var odroczono=(wyplata*0.06);
              var dowyplaty = (premia-odroczono);
                if(dowyplaty<0) {
                  dowyplaty=0;
                  odroczono=premia;
          }
          
        }
      }

      } else if (miesiac=="Czerwiec") {
          for (let a =0;a<bazaSlownikDane.length;a++) {
            if (bazaSlownikDane[a][1]==pesel){
              var wyplata=bazaSlownikDane[a][7];
              var odroczono=(wyplata*0.06);
              var dowyplaty = (premia-odroczono);
              if(dowyplaty<0) {
                dowyplaty=0;
                odroczono=premia;
          }
          
        }
      }

      } else if (miesiac=="Lipiec") {
          for (let a =0;a<bazaSlownikDane.length;a++) {
            if (bazaSlownikDane[a][1]==pesel){
              var wyplata=bazaSlownikDane[a][8];
              var odroczono=(wyplata*0.06);
              var dowyplaty = (premia-odroczono);
                if(dowyplaty<0) {
                  dowyplaty=0;
                  odroczono=premia;
          }
          
        }
      }

      } else if (miesiac=="Sierpień") {
          for (let a =0;a<bazaSlownikDane.length;a++) {
            if (bazaSlownikDane[a][1]==pesel){
              var wyplata=bazaSlownikDane[a][9];
              var odroczono=(wyplata*0.06);
              var dowyplaty = (premia-odroczono);
              if(dowyplaty<0) {
                dowyplaty=0;
                odroczono=premia;
          }
          
        }
      }

      } else if (miesiac=="Wrzesień") {
          for (let a =0;a<bazaSlownikDane.length;a++) {
            if (bazaSlownikDane[a][1]==pesel){
              var wyplata=bazaSlownikDane[a][10];
              var odroczono=(wyplata*0.06);
              var dowyplaty = (premia-odroczono);
              if(dowyplaty<0) {
                dowyplaty=0;
                odroczono=premia;
          }
          
        }
      }

      } else if (miesiac=="Październik") {
          for (let a =0;a<bazaSlownikDane.length;a++) {
            if (bazaSlownikDane[a][1]==pesel){
              var wyplata=bazaSlownikDane[a][11];
              var odroczono=(wyplata*0.06);
              var dowyplaty = (premia-odroczono);
              if(dowyplaty<0) {
                dowyplaty=0;
                odroczono=premia;
          }
          
        }
      }

      } else if (miesiac=="Litopad") {
          for (let a =0;a<bazaSlownikDane.length;a++) {
            if (bazaSlownikDane[a][1]==pesel){
              var wyplata=bazaSlownikDane[a][12];
              var odroczono=(wyplata*0.06);
              var dowyplaty = (premia-odroczono);
              if(dowyplaty<0) {
                dowyplaty=0;
                odroczono=premia;
          }
          
        }
      }

      } else if (miesiac=="Grudzień") {
          for (let a =0;a<bazaSlownikDane.length;a++) {
            if (bazaSlownikDane[a][1]==pesel){
              var wyplata=bazaSlownikDane[a][13];
              var odroczono=(wyplata*0.06);
              var dowyplaty = (premia-odroczono);
              if(dowyplaty<0) {
                dowyplaty=0;
                odroczono=premia;
          }
          
        }
      }

        } 

        var status = "Nowe zgłoszenie";
        var wynik = [[miesiac,nazwisko,imie,biuro,pesel,przelozony,premia,wyplata,dowyplaty,odroczono,status]];
        var wynikZespol = [["Wysłano",dowyplaty,odroczono]];

        Logger.log("wynik: "+wynik);
        Logger.log("wynik zespołu: "+wynikZespol);

        var freeRow = bazaBaza.getLastRow()+1;
        bazaBaza.getRange(freeRow,1,1,11).setValues(wynik); //wstawianie wartości do arkusza Baza
        sheet.getRange(i+1,7,1,3).setValues(wynikZespol);   //wstawianie wartości do arkusza Premie, poszczególnych zespołów    


    }

  }
   

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    if (licznik==0) {
      ui.alert('Brak informacji do wysyłki odnośnie wysokości premii');
    } else {
      ui.alert("Raport został wysłany w ilości: "+licznik+" sztuk");

    }
   
    
 
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code related to `PREMIA`?

Comment: @lamblichus i just added

Answer (score 0):

You should move the call to get the Spreadsheet ID inside the try-catch block.

```
try {
  const ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
  PREMIA.importDane(ssID);
} catch (error)
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. My library "PREMIA" has the part with the SpreadsheetApp.openbyId("ID") and not everybody has acces to the this spreasdSheet including me. But i thought when i'm using try and catch, then the error will not appear

Answer (score 0):

#### This might be a bug:

Error messages corresponding to methods [openById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid) or [openByUrl](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl) get displayed in the logs even if the method is wrapped in [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch).

#### Reported in Issue Tracker:

This has been previously reported in Issue Tracker:

- [SpreadsheetApp.openById re-throws catched exception](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/189730925)

Anyone affected by this, please consider [subscribing to this issue by starring it](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#subscribing_by_starring_an_issue) in order to keep track of it and to help prioritizing it.

#### More details:

Please note that using a library or not is irrelevant here, since this is reproducible even if this method is not called directly in the main code:

```
function myFunction() {
  try {
    SpreadsheetApp.openById("SS_ID");
  } catch(err) {
    console.log("ERROR");
  }
}
```

In both cases, the code successfully enters and executes the `catch` block, but the error message is logged at the end, and the status of the Execution is set to `Failed`:

[image]

Also note that similar methods like [DocumentApp.openById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#openbyidid) do not show this behavior.